# View in xml or java class?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator

Which is more preferable or standard approach to display the UI for activity in Android Application Development either a Java Class or XML layout ?

Please provide the reason for the same.

Comment: XML layout is preferable

Comment: @Shraddha can you please provide the reason ? Is XML-layout memory friendly or less memory-consuming you see ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you want to achieve, for example if you have requirement to display data from database query in linear layout, because of dynamic data you don't know what fields you need to define and how many fields you need to define, in this case, you will have XML as skeleton and will implement real field add logic in java code.

Another case where you know ahead of time how many fields your layout may have, for example login  form, in this case it is very simple to define in XML, I feel the main reason is you don't need to write whole lot of java code.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer to my question, but can you please update me which of the approach is more memory-friendly and which one is more memory consuming ?

Comment: I don't have any numbers to backup this theory, but from my coding experience, I feel java code would take less memory, reason is, eventhough you define layout in XML, android API parses it and generates corresponding java objects to do rendering (or) manipulation of data etc.,. I may be wrong too.  I think it is worth to have another question with this title, someone with numbers may able to explain clearly.

Comment: thanks for the answer, liked the way you justified your answer.
I have added a question as per your suggestion. :)
Please have a look : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8876097/memory-friendly-view-in-xml-or-java-class

Comment: You are welcome! that is what we are here for. Enjoy programming.

Answer (score 1):

The standard approach would be using an XML layout. They are generally easier to set up, maintain and re-use. However, all views can also be created or modified programmatically during run-time.

So basically, it's up to you. The XML way is the general approach but you're free to use the programmatic way as you see fit.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer to my question, but can you please update me which of the approach is more memory-friendly and which one is more memory consuming ?

Comment: I'm not sure on that one, but I can imagine them being similar. The XML approach might be more memory-friendly due to the Android system being mostly build towards the XML aproach. Either way, all views will need to be loaded into the memory during the building of the interface, so I doubt there will be a large difference.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the use case.
XML layout is useful for designing static UI which is not going to change. If your UI components are added or removed depending on the code it can only be done using Java code.

Comment: This is not entirely true. Even the elements that you called "static" can be modified during run-time whether they come from an XML file or not. You can add new elements to existing XML layouts through code, and can remove (well, hide completely) elements as well.