# Memory friendly : View in xml or java class?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator

I am starting with development in android apoplications, but not sure about the creation of views.
Which one of the two is more preferable in terms of memory-consumption for creation of views : XML or Java Class ?

Can you please suggest which approach is more memory-friendly either XML or Java classes for creation of view ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is ultimately Java behind the xml..

so both are same as creating from Java or using xml.

XML help us to customize `Views` quickly and drag & drop graphically.

The Layout tricks actually works. (For example: [Here](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-merge.html) is an illustration to optimize the memory consumption.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, will get back to you if I need anything more.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just starting with the development and you are new to android..go with XML its easier to understand and experiment with.there are a lot of tutorials around.

Java classes are usually used to set view dynamically..so i would suggest start with XML and move to simple Java tutorials.
with memory friendly part(i dint get what you are trying to say) if its about the load time or the CPU usage.its non the less same.

Answer (score 0):

For the purpose of memory-consumption XML Views are best to use but if you want to make your View Dynamic as you receive data from the Server or from any other resource at run time Then you can use Java for creating those Views.

Comment: thanks for the answer can you please justify the same or provide me link for more details regarding the same...?